# Why is there silence in Heaven after the seventh seal is opened?

Tags: christianity, revelation

When the seventh seal is opened, there is half an hour of silence in Heaven (KJ21):

> <sup>8:1</sup> And when He had opened the seventh seal, there was silence in Heaven about the space of half an hour.

Why? And, is there some significance to the "space of half an hour"?

Comment: This might get some good answers on either https://christianity.stackexchange.com or https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com.